# Check if file (ClickOnce) exists using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, clickonce

I am trying to find out whether or not a file exists, before trying to download it. The file is a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application.

I have already tried the following code, but this does not work (maybe because the URL is on a different server and domain?);

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //File does not exist
    },
    success: function()
    {
        // File exists
    }
});
```

Is there another solution, or is there a means to get this one to work?

Comment: Call a method on the server that can talk to the IO system instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should not work if the URL is on a different server. If you want to make this work, you will need control over the server where the URL is downloaded from. If so, you should set 
the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the name of the server from which your JavaScript is loaded.

See Stack Overflow question *[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208)* for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make Cross-Domain Calls this easily [(CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). It is better and safer to call a script on your server which checks for the existence of the file and returns an according result.

Comment: @drbaltar I don't understand you... How do you want to do your ajax request in the first place if you don't know the servername?

Answer (score 0):

Besides what the others have said, you should also check the `errorThrown` argument to the error function to be "Not Found". Otherwise you may be assuming a file doesn't exist when really a different error occurred.

> When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."